# My events do not work correctly unless I alert the variables? Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I've got two events: an `onFocus` (`saveOld`) and an `OnChange` (`showPoints`). When a user focuses in the drop down I use the `jquery.data` function to save the old value of the drop down. When the user changes the value of the drop down I check to see if the old value was larger then then the current value. If so, I adjust the total accordingly. But this only works when I alert the old value after getting it from the `.data` function in my `onChange`. Without the alert nothing happens.

```
function showPoints(pointCategory, ddlAmount, name){
    old = jQuery.data(document.body,name);
    
    alert(old);

    var Points = parseInt($('p#points').html());

    if(old > ddlAmount){
       diff =  old - ddlAmount;
       currentPoints = Points + (diff * pointCategory);
    }else{
       currentPoints = Points - (ddlAmount * pointCategory);
    }
    $('p#points').html(currentPoints);
}//showPoints

function saveOld(oldAmount, name){
    $(document.body).data(name,oldAmount);
}
```

Without the alert in `showPoints()` this does not work correctly. What is going wrong?

EDIT: Note that I have already tried a `this.delay(1000)` where the alert should be. Still did not work.

Comment: show `onfocus` and `onChange` code.

Comment: I would assume that the time the alert takes to display and for you to click it gives the browser time to do something it doesn't have time to if there is no alert. Are you running your code on $.ready() ? If not, you should be.

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan these functions are what are called when the events fire. onFocus = saveOld and onChange = showPoints

Comment: @x3ro I have an external js file that contains the two functions. How should I use the $.ready function? Im a jquery noob...

Comment: The functions are not written to fire on .ready. They fire during events listed above onChange and onFocus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing onfocus to onclick and also save your current value to .data in the end of showPoints like so:

```
$('p#points').html(currentPoints);
$(document.body).data(name,currentPoints);
```

I would use local variables inside showPoints function.

Answer (score 1):

When you Alert you lose focus from element. So its a changed scenario for the `alert()` case.

So I would say you Save the value `onBlur` (called when u leave the control.)

Comment: This works well as long as a user clicks on the screen after selecting an amount and not on a different drop down. Unfortunately this does not work well enough to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

delay(1000) will not help as it only adds processing time and not give more time for the function to process. I would go with x3ro's solution and check how the function is called.